# Have $this in PHP implicit function before PHP 5.4.0

Tags: php, closures

According to http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php, in PHP 5.3 `$this` is not accessible from inside an implicit function, even if the function is defined in a context where `$this` exists. Is there any way to work around this limitation? (by the way, upgrading the PHP installation on the webserver is not possible)

The way I would like to use the implicit function is to define a callback which is a member function of some object. More precisely, I would like to do something like

```
$callback = function() { return $this->my_callback(); }
```

Actually, an event better syntax would be

```
$callback = $this->my_callback
```

but I cannot make it work (PHP dies with "Fatal error: Function name must be a string" when I try to execute the callback).

Comment: If only everything were a first-class-object in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should do the work:

```
$object = $this ;
$callback = function() use ($object) { return $object->my_callback(); } ;
```

`use` will bring an accessible variable (in our case the reference of the object) upon its declaration to the function scope, so you will not have to send it as a parameter.

Sometimes it is even better to use such a varname as `$self` or `$that` so to be more clear.

Comment: Definitely the best approach for my case, although I find it embarassing that such a trick is needed and one cannot directly write `use ($this)`. Thanks.

Comment: I also faced that problem before `PHP 5.4` and I know that feel :)

Comment: It's worth noting the main difference with this approach from 5.4: you cannot access protected/private methods using it. As of 5.4 you *do* have access to the non-public functionality because the closure is bound to the scope of the class in which it's created. Also, 5.3 is moving towards end of life and is now [only supported to the extent that it needs security fixes.](http://news.php.net/php.internals/67734) **You need to upgrade.**

Answer (score 1):

```
$function = array($this, 'my_callback');
```

(perhaps combined with `call_user_func()` )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pass variables to the callback function. I haven't worked with closures in PHP, but I think this would work for you:

```
$callback = function($instance) { return $instance->my_callback(); }
$callback($this);
```

Or if the callback is triggered outside the current class.

```
$callback($myClassInstance);
```